# What are "non-community wiki answers"?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

I am looking to get a few tag badges, and I see that they are given for "non-community wiki answers".

What are those and how are they different from regular SO answers, if they are?

Comment: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) should answer your question.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. "non community wiki answers" returned nothing in the search bar, so I think the question is legit and probably doesn't deserve a downvote...

Comment: For what it's worth, that downvote is not mine, and I personally believe we should refrain from downvoting cross-site duplicates with the Overmeta, as we are responsible for this situation in the first place.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate from Uber-meta [What are Non-Community Wikis in Stack Exchange and why is it named so?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218168/what-are-non-community-wikis-in-stack-exchange-and-why-is-it-named-so)

Comment: The phrasing of "non-community wiki" in the badge descriptions needs fixed.  It is not clear to non-native speakers.

Comment: @psubsee2003: [Change "non-community wiki" in tag badge descriptions to something less confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218179/change-non-community-wiki-in-tag-badge-descriptions-to-something-less-confusin)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom did you notice who answered that question :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Non-community wiki" posts are simply posts that are *not* [community wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

You'll notice that a community wiki post shows editing information for all users active on the post:

[image: CW]

On regular posts, you'll see a user's flair instead:

[image: Regular post]